# Ionic - drawImage() does not work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, canvas, ionic-framework, drawimage

The `drawImage` function is working fine if `<canvas>` is defined in HTML.
Please check my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ce0ow6qk/7/)

But, When I create the canvas using `createElement('canvas')` it does not work.

I have tried to convert the image to canvas in the following ways

**Try 1:**

```
$scope.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$scope.canvas.width = 500;
$scope.canvas.height =1000;
var ctx = $scope.canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
     alert("image is loaded");
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

 };
img.src="img/default_subject.png";
```

In this way the canvas shows only **blank** screen when tried to display using `$scope.canvas.toDataURL()`

**Try 2:**

In this try , I have just moved img.src inside of `onload()` function

```
img.onload = function() {
img.src="img/default_subject.png";
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```

This try also not working.

**Try 3:**
In this try, I changed  `var img = new Image();` to `var img = document.createElement('img')`

```
$scope.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$scope.canvas.width = 500;
$scope.canvas.height =1000;
var ctx = $scope.canvas.getContext('2d');

var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
     alert("image is loaded");
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

 };
img.src="img/default_subject.png";
```

But, there is no breakthrough .

Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the canvas element, you need to add the canvas element to the document. I have modified your JSFiddle example to use JavaScript to create the canvas element.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height =1000;
document.getElementById("canvasContainer").appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
     alert("image is loaded");
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src="http://www.download-free-wallpaper.com/img88/xpwwiirymrkfcacywpax.jpg";
```

```html
<div id="canvasContainer"></div>
```